# Split string from a list keyCode in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a list of keyCode which stand for separator keys. After user inputs a string (from a textbox), how can I split that string by a list of keyCode? So far split() function is allowed string or regexp, I found nothing when converting keyCode to regexp.

What should I do in this case?

For example:

```
separators = [ 
    mdConstants.KEY_CODE.COMMA // 188
    mdConstants.KEY_CODE.DASH: // 189
    ...
]

Input -> Output
------------------
abc-def -> [ abc, def ]
abc-def.efg -> [ abc, def, efg ]
```

Comment: I just updated the question, please double check again

Comment: Key codes and characters are two very different things. It doesn’t even make sense to try and split a string (which is a list of characters) by key codes. You need to get the characters that those key codes correspond to first.

Comment: @misorude I've just figured it out. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions in split:

```
// eg ,-
var separators = [44, 45];
var myText = "this, is a - test";

var regex = "[" + separators.map(function (c) { return String.fromCharCode(c); }).join("") + "]"; 

var groupedItems = myText.split(new RegExp(regex));
console.log(groupedItems);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure if that's what you want, but here is a stub at it with my understanding of your question:

```
const separators = [ 
    ",",
    "-",
    "."
];

// make regex pattern from your separators.
// pipe serves as a char separator
// double is backslash for escaping chars
let pattern = new RegExp('\\' + separators.join('|\\'), "g");

// user input
let userInput = "abc-def.efg";

// resulting array of words split by your separators
let result = userInput.split(pattern);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank for answer me. Is it different if I use 
var regex = "[" + this. separators.join("") + "]";
var tokens = chip.split(new RegExp(regex));
of Russell comment

Comment: Found it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 1):

It is OK to use `RegExp` object to split a string.

```js
//assuming an object is given
const mdConstants = {
  "KEY_CODE": {
    "COMMA": ",",
    "DASH": "-",
    "DOT": "."
  }
};

//you can create separator list

const separators = Object.keys(mdConstants.KEY_CODE).map(k => '[' + mdConstants.KEY_CODE[k] + ']'); //sanitize symbols to avoid RegExp special character conflicts

//create RegExp object
const re = new RegExp(separators.join('|'));

//and use it

console.log('abc-def.ghi,jkl'.split(re));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for `onKeyDown` event on the input box, this will give you an event object. Your function can look something like this.

`var tempWord = "";`

`var arrayYouWant = [];`
`var separators = [];`

```
function onKeyDownHandler (event) {
    var value = event.target.value;
    var keyCode = event.which || event.keyCode;
    if (separators.indexOf(keyCode) === -1) {
        tempWord += value;
    } else {
        arrayYouWant.push(tempWord);
        tempWord = "";
    }
}
```

This is a vague implementation, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: I have limited access to this event so I can not handle it

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing all separators with the first separator and then do the split using javascript's split function and the first separator.

Here is an example:

```
var a = 'abc-def.efg';

for (var i = 0; i<separators.length; i++){
    a = a.replace(separators[i],separators[0]);
} 

var a_split = a.split(separators[0]);

console.log(a_split);
```